# Converting epoch time to localtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and one of the columns is time represented as the epoch time. The dataframe looks like  this:

```
0    1539340322842
1    1539340426841
2    1539340438482
3    1539340485658
4    1539340495920
Name: Time, dtype: int64
```

I tried this
`df["local_time"] = df.epoch_time.dt.tz_localize("UTC")` but this doesn't give me the result in local time. This is the result of the above operation:

```
                        local_time  
0 1970-01-01 00:25:39.340322842+00:00  
1 1970-01-01 00:25:39.340426841+00:00  
2 1970-01-01 00:25:39.340438482+00:00  
3 1970-01-01 00:25:39.340485658+00:00  
4 1970-01-01 00:25:39.340495920+00:00
```

The other thing that gave me the result I want is this:

```
def convert_time(x):                                              
    return time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(x/1000)) 

df["local_time"] = df["epoch_time"].apply(convert_time)
```

Is there anyway that I can vectorize the above operation to get the datetime in the format I want?

Comment: `time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(1539403981))`. You can specify the format within `strftime`

Comment: What is the required output?

Comment: @psychoCoder can you show an example?

Comment: @mlRocks `time.strftime('%d-%B-%Y %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(1539403981))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, I think you need pandas `to_datetime` with `units='s'`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Time/1000,unit='s')
0   2018-10-12 10:32:02.842000008
1   2018-10-12 10:33:46.841000080
2   2018-10-12 10:33:58.482000113
3   2018-10-12 10:34:45.657999992
4   2018-10-12 10:34:55.920000076
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or using `astype` as:

```
((df.Time)/1000).astype("datetime64[s]")
0   2018-10-12 10:32:02
1   2018-10-12 10:33:46
2   2018-10-12 10:33:58
3   2018-10-12 10:34:45
4   2018-10-12 10:34:55
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Time/1000,unit='s',utc=True)
0   2018-10-12 10:32:02.842000008+00:00
1   2018-10-12 10:33:46.841000080+00:00
2   2018-10-12 10:33:58.482000113+00:00
3   2018-10-12 10:34:45.657999992+00:00
4   2018-10-12 10:34:55.920000076+00:00
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

---

Since `'Asia/Kolkata'` is `05:30:00` ahead just add `Timedelta`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Time/1000,unit='s')+pd.Timedelta("05:30:00")
0   2018-10-12 16:02:02.842000008
1   2018-10-12 16:03:46.841000080
2   2018-10-12 16:03:58.482000113
3   2018-10-12 16:04:45.657999992
4   2018-10-12 16:04:55.920000076
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: This looks good, but it's in UTC. And if do `df.locatime.dt.tz_localize('Asia/Kolkata')`, it adds the time diff but don't convert it actually